# Getting complex solution with Matlab ode45

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I'm trying to solve such an ODE:
$$U'(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha  DU(\alpha) + A\alpha + C + \sqrt{BU(\alpha)}}{D(\alpha^2 - \alpha)}$$

with boundary condition $U(a) = 0.$

I have such a problem that if the solution of $y$ would have a complex component, such as $1.1462 + 0.0000i$. If I take the absolute value of the radicand, the generated solutions will no longer be complex. However, those solutions are not what I desire. Is there anything I can do to avoid this?

My Matlab code is like:

```
clearvars;
A=-4.32;
B=4;
C=1.2;
D=0.8;

a=0.2778;
odefun_mon_pc1=@(t,y) (t*D*y+A*t+C+sqrt(B*y))/((t*t-t)*D);
tspan2=[a 0.99];
options=odeset('Reltol',1e-10);
[t,y]=ode45(odefun_mon_pc1,tspan2,0.0001,options);
h_pc_mon=plot(t,y,'--blue','linewidth',1);
```

Comment: It looks to me as if your parameter values are such that $U'(a)$ is meant to be zero (or very close to zero) at the initial condition.  Is that the case?  It's so sensitive that replacing $U(a) = 0$ with $U(a) = 0.0001$ makes $U'(a) < 0$, which means it very soon becomes negative.